# Why isn't this code giving me an error with --noImplicitAny?

Tags: typescript, types

This code doesn't show me any errors in the TypeScript playground or from `tsc`, even when I enable the `--noImplicitAny` flag. Why not? If I hover `methodName` in the playground, it says `let methodName: any`, so it seems to be getting that type; and I haven't explicitly provided it, so that would be...implicit.

```
let methodName;
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    methodName = "foo";
} else {
    methodName = 42;
}
console.log(methodName);
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20methodName%3B%0Aif%20(Math.random()%20%3C%200.5)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(methodName)%3B) *(unfortunately, you have to manually go into Options and turn on the option, playground links don't retain the options)*

When it didn't give me an error, I half expected hovering to show me `let methodName: string | number` (which would have made me think: "Wow, TypeScript's type inference goes really deep..."), but it says `any` instead.

Even just `let methodName;` on its own doesn't give me an error either, but I figured it was basically being ignored because it wasn't used, which is why I have the `if`/`else` above.

Adding `export` in front of it *does* give me the `Variable 'methodName' implicitly has an 'any' type.` error I was expected, so that may point to some reason.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but it seems that Typescript can infer this as `string | number`. If you pass it into a function that takes a `string` parameter, it throws an error: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20methodName%3B%0Aif%20(Math.random()%20%3C%200.5)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20foo(x%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afoo(methodName)%3B

Comment: And if you pass it into console.log, and a function that takes a `string | number`, it infers it correctly: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20methodName%3B%0Aif%20(Math.random()%20%3C%200.5)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20foo(x%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(methodName)%3B%0A%0Afoo(methodName)%3B.

Comment: @wvteijlingen - That's very interesting. So the hint provided by the tooltip may be incorrect, and my guess that TypeScript is really inferring `string|number` may be correct.

Comment: When you hover over it in the console log, you can actually see that it inferred `string | number` after the if/else (i.e., it narrowed the type afterwards). I'd still consider filing an issue here, it at the very least seems odd.

Comment: As others point out the type at the time of `console.log` is `string | number`. Typescript does flow analysis, so at first the type is any, inside the if it is still any, but after assignment it no longer is `any` it is `number | string`. If remove all assignments the type will be `undefined`.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir But shouldn't the declaration still give the implicit any error since it *does* infer `any` at this point?

Comment: If it would the whole evolving type feature of flow analysis would be useless. If you don't do any assignment to the variable you will get error if you try to use it in most (`let methodName;
methodName.bla(); // Object is possibly udefined even without strict null checks
`). BUt I agree it might be a bit surprising..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Thanks for all that. Now I'm getting even more confused, though (not your fault). Consider [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20methodName%3B%0Aconsole.log(methodName)%3B%0Aif%20(Math.random()%20%3C%200.5)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20methodName%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(methodName)%3B). `methodName` ends up having three separate types at four different times: Starts out `any`, then is `undefined`, then it's `any` again (?!), then `string|number`. Not a single error. (cont'd)

Comment: *(continuing)* I realize the fundamental issue here is that I don't declare a type, and that if I did it would fix it, but...them's some interesting type gymnastics going on. I'm wondering (at minimum) how helpful those gymnastics are when I've expressly asked TypeScript to tell me when I do stuff like this. :-)

Answer (score 5):

> This PR introduces control flow analysis for let and var variables
>   that have no type annotation and either no initial value or an initial
>   value of null or undefined.
>
> ```
> function f(cond: boolean) {
>     let x;
>     if (cond) {
>         x = "hello";
>         x;  // string
>     }
>     else {
>         x = 123;
>         x;  // number
>     }
>     return x;  // string | number
> }
>
> function g(cond: boolean) {
>     let y = null;
>     if (cond) {
>         y = "hello";
>     }
>     return y;  // string | null
> }
> ```
>
> In the example above, x and y implicitly have declared types of any
>   but control flow analysis can determine their actual types at every
>   reference. Therefore, no errors are reported even when the example is
>   compiled with --noImplicitAny.
>
> In time it is possible that control flow analysis will be able to more
>   accurately determine types of references to outer variables from
>   nested functions in some cases, but given that nested functions are
>   first class objects that can be arbitrarily passed around and called,
>   it is effectively impossible to analyze all such scenarios.

[*Copied from explanation given on this feature by Anders Hejlsberg*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11263)